# Proving that a compactly supported square integrable function is in $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{d})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

if I know that a function $f$ $\in L^{2}(\mathbb R^{d})$ is supported in a compact ball in $\mathbb R^{d}$, how do I prove it is in $L^{1}(\mathbb R^{d})$

From the square integrability I know that $$\int_{\mathbb supp(f)} |f|^{2} d \mu \le C \mu(supp(f))$$ for some constant C, then I know that $f(supp(f))$ is bounded, I need to show that it is closed as well to conclude that it is compact, but that will not be true in general if $f$ is not continuous.

How am I supposed to start given what I have?

Comment: There are many discontinuous, compactly supported $L^2$ functions. E.g. in $d=1$, consider $f = 1_{[0,1]} - 1_{(1,2]}$.

Comment: The function $f=1_B$ where $B$ is the unit ball is supported in a compact ball but is not equivalent to any continuous function.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted the statement then, my goal is to prove that $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb R^{d}) ($, but to prove that I have to prove that $f$ is continuous which is not true in general.

Comment: Then you should delete your question and ask a new one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that new question will be a duplicate. Here's a hint for it: Holder's inequality.

Comment: Let $S$ be the support then $\int |f| = \int |f| 1_S$. Now use Cauchy schwartz.

Comment: Thank you, is my answer now correct? (used Holder's inequality)

Comment: $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset L^{1, loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty]$ as a consequence of Holder's inequality.

Comment: I disapprove your course of action. Your original question has nothing to do with its present form after your edit.  The first two comments still refer to the original question. Ediiting a question should serve to clarify things which have been unclear or to correct mistakes - not to replace it by a completely different question. Imagine if you would have received answers to your original question. These would now be obsolete and other readers would be astonished which rubbish these answers contain.

Comment: @PaulFrost I understand that, I am very sorry, and I would have definitely made a totally new question, but wouldn't the first two comments be 'adding' to the question rather than being irrelevant at all? You definitely know this more than me, so if you believe that this could misguide others, I am up to re-ask the question and answer it again.

Comment: @cazanova No, don't re-ask now. My comment was of a general nature. But I would be happy if you bear it in  mind for future cases.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume $f\ge 0$, let $X=f^{-1}([1, \infty))$. Then, $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} f dx = \int_X f dx + \int_{\text{Supp(f)}\setminus X} f dx$$ $$\le \int_X f^2 dx + m(\text{Supp}(f)) \le \|f\|_2^2 + m(\text{Supp}(f))<\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

By using Holder's inequality,

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^{d}} |fh| d \mu \le ( \int_{\mathbb R^{d}} |f|^{2} d \mu)^{1/2} .(\int_{\mathbb R^{d}} |h|^{2} d \mu)^{1/2} $$

By taking $h = \chi_{supp(f)}$

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^{d}} |f| d \mu = \int_{supp(f)} |f| d \mu + \int_{(supp(f))^{c}} |f| d \mu \le ( \int_{supp(f)} |f|^{2} d \mu)^{1/2}. (\int_{supp(f)} 1 d \mu)^{1/2}$$

Since $supp(f)$ is compact, $\mu(supp(f))$ is finite, $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb R^{d})$, then its norm is finite, then $\int_{\mathbb R^{d}} |f| d \mu < \infty$

Comment: You can't take $h=1$, it should be the characteristic function of the support.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, otherwise I would have only proven $f \in L^{1}(supp(f))$

Comment: Not really, you would have shown that $\int |fh| \le \infty$.

Comment: But that would happen if I considered the whole $\mathbb{R^{d}}$, correct? If I only take $supp(f)$ into consideration I don't get that problem?

Comment: Yes, but earlier you had $h=1$.